# ¿No es necesario inicializar un acumulador?

Tags: vb.net

Ando con esta duda ya que me gustaría saber el por qué no es necesario inicializar un acumulador en vb.net

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim valor, suma As Integer

    Do
        Console.Write("Ingrese valor (0 pera finalizar):")
        valor = Integer.Parse(Console.ReadLine())

        suma = suma + valor
    Loop While valor <> 0

    Console.WriteLine(suma)

    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

End Module
```

En otros lenguajes como C o C# te piden que la asignes/inicialices con un valor pero en VB.Net no parece necesario. ¿Por qué?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bueno, en C# hay que diferenciar entre "Campos" y "Variables Locales". Los campos no necesitan ser inicializados, mientras que las variables locales si. Lo vemos en un ejemplo:

```
class Prueba
{
    int i; //Al estar definido en la clase, es un Campo

    public Prueba()
    {
        i+=1; 
    }
}
```

Este ejemplo compila perfectamente, y `i` se inicializa con el valor por defecto de `int`, o sea `0`

Sin embargo,el siguiente ejemplo no compila:

```
class Prueba
{
    public Prueba()
    {
        int i; //Al estar definido en un método, es una variable local
        i+=1; 
    }
}
```

Esto se hace para asegurar la fiabilidad de la aplicación, y se explica perfectamente en la referencia del lenguaje C# en el apartado [5.3 Asignación definitiva](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/aa691172(v=vs.71).aspx)

En cuanto a VB.Net, es un lenguaje que ha heredado ciertos hábitos del Visual Basic original, entre ellos la no necesidad de inicializar las variables locales. Es un lenguaje en el que es algo más fácil pegarse un tiro en el pie, y por eso se recomienda activar las opciones `Option Strict` y `Option Explicit`, para prevenir problemas dificiles de depurar.

Resumiendo: ¿Por que es asi? Porque cuando se definieron ambos lenguajes, se decidió que debia ser asi, no hay que darle muchas mas vueltas. C# es un lenguaje nuevo que ha aprendido de errores de anteriores lenguajes, mientras que VB.net tuvo que hacer algunas concesiones para resultar mas sencillo la transición desde Visual Basic.

Comment: "campo" o  "propiedad" ? o es lo mismo?

Comment: @lois6b En este caso, campo. Para ser una propiedad, debe tener un `getter` o `setter`o ambos. Un campo es una variable definida a nivel de clase.

Comment: ohhh, gracias ^^

Comment: @lois6b normalmente, propiedad se llama a la estructura que sirve para acceder a un campo privado desde fuera. Mira la definición [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) :)

Answer (score 3):

Muy sencillo: todos los tipos tienen un [*valor por defecto*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ee5a7s1.aspx#default) con el que son inicializados si no se indica un valor concreto al declararlos.

En el caso concreto de los `Integer`, dicho valor es `0`.

Comment: Y que `Option Strict` no está activado, vuelve VB.NET _"A pain in the @$#"_